# Rotate label text of bar chart by 90deg

Tags: d3.js, svg

How to rotate text of label of barchart in d3.js? I tried using 
`.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")` but it rotates the entire column.

**csv file:**

```
date,value
2013-01,53
2013-02,165
2013-03,269
2013-04,344
2013-05,376
2013-06,410
2013-07,421
2013-08,405
2013-09,376
2013-10,359
2013-11,392
2013-12,433
2014-01,455
2014-02,478
```

**code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
<script>
    // Code goes here

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    padding = -60; // space around the chart, not including labels
// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });


  svg.selectAll(".text")        
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
    //.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.date); }  ))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });         


  svg.selectAll("text")
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append("text")
         .text(function(d) {
       return d.value;
    })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return i * (width / data.length);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
           return height - (d * 4);
      });

    });

  // now add titles to the axes
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
      .attr("transform", "translate("+ (padding/2) +","+(height/2)+")rotate(-90)")  // text is drawn off the screen top left, move down and out and rotate
      .text("Value");
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
      .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width/2) +","+(height-(padding))+")")  // centre below axis
      .text("Date");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is actually the expected behaviour, since the `rotate` function of the `transform` attribute rotates all the elements around their origins, not around their centres.

The easiest solution is passing the optional `x` and `y` arguments to `rotate`:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-90," + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
    //x and y here ------------^------------------^
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      // Code goes here

      var csv = `date,value
2013-01,53
2013-02,165
2013-03,269
2013-04,344
2013-05,376
2013-06,410
2013-07,421
2013-08,405
2013-09,376
2013-10,359
2013-11,392
2013-12,433
2014-01,455
2014-02,478`;


      var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 70,
          left: 40
        },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      padding = -60; // space around the chart, not including labels
      // Parse the date / time
      var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");

      var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.05);

      var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m"));

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(10);

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
      });

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Value ($)");

      svg.selectAll("bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.date);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });


      svg.selectAll(".text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(-90," + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
        })
        .attr("x", (function(d) {
          return x(d.date);
        }))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("dy", "1.3em")
        .attr("dx", "0.2em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        });


      svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return i * (width / data.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return height - (d * 4);
        });


      // now add titles to the axes
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")rotate(-90)") // text is drawn off the screen top left, move down and out and rotate
        .text("Value");
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height - (padding)) + ")") // centre below axis
        .text("Date");

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```